# remove whitespace from JSON (api response) in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, whitespace

I call an api in javascript and capture the response

```
var response = client.get(serviceURI);
var result101 = response.getProperty("content");
```

and later parsing the JSON to edit and repost but its throwing parsing error because there are new lines in json response.

```
var resultJSON = JSON.parse(result101);
```

How can I remove new lines from the response? I have tried

```
result101 = result101.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

but this is not working for me..

EDIT: Part of result101:

```
   "description": "Hello world.
Test Description here.. ",
   "forms": [
```

Comment: What does `result101` look like?

Comment: Where are the newline characters in the string? Is it characters that are not correctly encoded inside strings? Newline characters in a JSON string is not a problem unless they break the syntax. Broken JSON sounds more like a problem for the one maintaining the API than something that should be fixed on the client side.

Comment: @Derek included the part of result101 thats causing issue.

Comment: @Guffa yes I believe newline char in JSON is breaking the syntax..

Comment: The JSON is broken. That should be fixed in the API, not on the client side. The replace that you have should remove line breaks, but there might be other characters that are not correctly escaped, like tab characters, backslashes and quotation marks. Those should be escaped when the JSON is created, there is no reliable way to fix for example unescaped quotation marks afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trim() method in Javascript that will remove the whitespaces characters from both ends of a string and returns a new string, without modifying the original string and all the line terminator characters. For example:

```
const value = '        Hi everyone!           ';

console.log(greeting);
// expected output: "        Hi everyone!           ";

console.log(greeting.trim());
// expected output: "Hi everyone!";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following code :

`result101.trim();`